# Kibana -> SSL enabled nginx'ed proxied ElasticsSearch w/basic Authentication Enabled

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to configure my Kibana instance to communicate with my nginx proxied SSL/Basic Authentication enabled Elasticsearch Client.

The curl command run from the same machine has no issues.

```
$ curl https://user:password@10.1.141.41:9200 --insecure
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Jeanne-Marie Beaubier",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster01",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "e43676b1385b8125d647f593f7202acbd816e8ec",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Kibana config:

```
$ cat config/kibana.yml
server.port: 5601
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.url: "https://10.1.141.41:9200"
elasticsearch.preserveHost: true
elasticsearch.username: user
elasticsearch.password: password
elasticsearch.ssl.verify: false
```

Error on startup of Kibana

```
$ bin/kibana -c config/kibana.yml | grep error
  log   [15:59:40.694] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Authorization Exception
```

Environment:

```
Kibana 4.2.0
ElasticSearch 1.7.2
No searchGuard
No Shield
```

Comment: how to setup ssl for elasticsearch 9200

Answer (score 1):

Kibana 4.2.0 supports Elasticsearch 2.0 or later.